# obtaining the signature of a Java Type as a String

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, javassist

I need to obtain (as a String) the *type signatures* of certain Java types.

For example, this is the type signature of certain [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html):

```
Lorg/mapackage/MyClass<Ljava/lang/String;>;
```

I need this in the context of an application being developed with Javassist.

To explain better what I am looking for, I show an extract of a method `createGetter` that uses Javassist to generate a getter method for a private field. The type of the field is a parameterized type (i.e., it uses generics).

The `createGetter` method receives as a first parameter the type of the field, the second parameter is the name of the field, and the third is the class where the method should be added:

```
public CtMethod createGetter(Type propertyType, String propertyName, CtClass ctDeclaringClass) {
    CtMethod ctGetterMethod = ...

    if(propertyType instanceof ParameterizedType //parameterized "single" type
      || propertyType instanceof GenericArrayType) { //parameterized array
        String signature = asGenericSignature(propertyType); //MISSING PIECE OF THE PUZZLE !
        ctGetterMethod.setGenericSignature(signature);
    }   
    return ctGetterMethod;
}
```

For example, if I have a class

```
public class TestClass{
  private MyClass<String> myField;
}
```

Then after calling the `createGetter` method for the field `myField`, the class becomes:

```
public class TestClass{
  private MyClass<String> myField;

  public MyClass<String> getMyField() {
    return MyClass<String> myField;
  }
}
```

The return type of the generated getter method should have the same generic signature as the  field (the code could compile without the method having the same generic signature of the field since having just the same class is fine for the compiler. The reasons I need it to have the same type generic signature are not explained here).

The code of the `createGetter` method illustrates that with Javassist, in order to set the generic type signature of a method, I need first to obtain such a type signature as a String (if there is another way please someone tell me).
I know the exact parameterized type the getter method should have since it is exactly the same than the field. But I have such type as an instance of [ParameterizedType](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/ParameterizedType.html).

My question is: how can I obtain these type signatures as strings (including type parameters data) given any arbitrary Java [Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) ?.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse internally uses descriptors/signatures for Java Source Code. These also include Generic information, which might be useful for you. The Interface IMethod might be a good starting point for investigation.